# Is there a NumPy function to compute partial sums?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given a 1-D array, `A` and a list of `n` unique and sorted indices `idx`, I would like to calculate sums of `A[idx[i]:idx[i + 1]]` for `i = 0` to `n - 1`. A for-based solution is:

```
S = [A[idx[i]:idx[i + 1]].sum() for i in range(n - 1)]
```

But I suppose this would be very slow if `n` is large as it is done at Python level. Is there a NumPy function to achieve this (hopefully faster)?

Comment: Thank you for your reminder.  I just did some clean-up of my older questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method of [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html):

```
np.add.reduceat(A, idx)[:-1]
```

The `[:-1]` is just there to remove the last element that `reduceat` appends with the sum from `idx[-1]` to `A.size`.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this method.

Comment: However, I think one should be careful about the case `idx[-1] == len(A)`.  (It raises `IndexError` in `reducecat`.) So perhaps this special case needs to be treated separately.